# Making big island with ocean surrounding it in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain

**How can I make a big island *(open world style)* with water surrounding it?**

I don't think that adding a big water prefab *(standard asset)* to the center of the island with big scales is a good idea, because it would be always rendered to the user which uses high amount of resources.

- Should I add more, different sized water prefabs to the shore?
- Which one is a better practice?

Comment: You need to explain your desired outcome further. Is this a block world? Is this an infinite world? What have you tried? Etc... Look at the terrain tool.

Comment: Somebody mentioned that I should make a question about my other problem because 2 not related questions in question is not a good idea :(

Comment: oh I remember now, yes I see your edit. My bad. :)

Comment: No problem , it happens :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **large** water object placed under land **won't be frustrum culled** because some part of it exists in the camera frustrum (unless you look straight up).  Because of this **it will** be part of the back-to-front drawing pipeline and thus **is not efficient**.  This is the danger of using over-sized polygons and/or extremely large childless objects.

If the water consisted of a individual objects; each with its prefab and mesh; then objects "off screen" could be trivially culled. Therefore you should use multiple prefabs of sufficient size so as to cullable at times via the frustrum.

Answer (score 1):

Use the water asset that comes with standard assets, make it large and just create your island ontop of it. Unity also only renders what the player can see in the frustum camera, so it wont render all the water (it used to as it was a bug but its been fixed now i think). You can also look into occlusion culling

Comment: @Tudvari A "large" water object placed under an "island" won't be frustrum culled because some part of it exists in the camera frustrum (unless you are looking straight up)